# Examples of Markov chains

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

I will give a talk to undergrad students about Markov chains. I would like to present several concrete real-world examples. However, I am not good with coming up with them.

Drunk man taking steps on a line, gambler's ruin, perhaps some urn problems.

But I would like to have more. I would favour eye-catching, curious, prosaic ones. Specially if there has been a paper about it. For example, I remember reading years back a paper, based on actual data, about the probability that a football player will change teams, or something like that.

Comment: Wouldn't math.SE be a better home for this question?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Nope, it's appropriate for both SEs. The question is on physical applications of Markov chains, and that is appropriate on the physics SE, being physics content, but also on the math SE since applications are discussed.

Comment: I considered posting it in math.SE, but I don't wat overly mathematical examples. I want physical ones.

Comment: http://setosa.io/ev/markov-chains/.  I admit that this is a guess, as I have not covered the subject, apologies if it's not applicable.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I was writing a brilliant answer when you closed it... I think in this case, it was not so cut and dry, we could have at least waited to accumulate 5 votes, and that way people writing answers would at least get a warning the effort may be in vain.

Comment: This question appears to be an open-ended list question with no unique correct answer, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @JamalS Sorry about that, but you should know the rules regarding list questions... (If you make an argument why this is not cut and dry like every other "Give me some examples of X" question, I'm certainly willing to listen and reopen, though)

Comment: @Marcel If you come into the chatroom with me, I'll help you write a question that fits the SE, that will get you the answer you want. Having some canonical answer on applications of Markov chains in physics would be nice.

Comment: @JamalS How do we go to chat room?